# Multiplication by %s when language dictates division rounds down by default

Tags: math, floating-point, erlang, solidity, fixed-point

In erlang:

```
cost(I, Miners) ->

  BasePrice = lists:nth(I, prices()),  

  Owned = lists:nth(I, Miners),

  Rate = increaseRate(I) / 100,

  Multiplier = math:pow((1 + Rate), Owned),

  floor(BasePrice * Multiplier).
```

for example, a base price of 8000, with an increase rate of 7, and I own 0

the price of the first one I expect to be: `8000`

when buying my second one, with an increase rate of 7, and I own 1

the price of the second one I expect to be:

```
Multiplier = 1.07

8000 * 1.07 =

8560
```

This all works fine. Now I have to implement this in Solidity, which doesn't do decimal math very well. It auto rounds down such that `3/2 == 1` in Solidity.

I want to recreate my cost function in Solidity.

```
function cost(uint _minerIndex, uint _owned) public view returns (uint) {
    uint basePrice = 8000;
    uint increaseRate = 7;
    return basePrice * ((1 + increaseRate / 100) ** _owned);
  }
```

`increaseRate / 100` will always return 0 if increaseRate is < 100.

How do I achieve this same effect?

From the documentation:

```
"Fixed point numbers are not fully supported by Solidity yet. They can be declared, but cannot be assigned to or from."
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution is

```
(basePrice * ((100+increaseRate)** _owned))/(100 ** _owned)
```

but it may fail also because of arithmetic overflow, depending on your numbers and the MaxInt supported by solidity.